# django - get a list of joins between two models based on a third model

Tags: python, django, model, django-queryset

I have three models that are set up like so:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    a = models.ForeignKey(to=A, null=True, blank=True)

class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    a = models.ForeignKey(to=A, null=True, blank=True)
```

The B-to-A relationship is one-one and the C-to-A relationship is many-one. I have a template where I want to show a list of all B.name, and for each B.name, have a list of C.name where C.a = B.a. What's the simplest way to do that?

I know I can just get the list of Bs and the list of Cs, and for each B get B.a and search the list of Cs for the matching C.a, but is there a cleaner way to just get a queryset that combines both?

---

example:

The **A** database looks like
| id | name  |
|----|-------|
| 1  | one   |
| 2  | two   |
| 3  | three |

The **B** database looks like
| id | name  | A |
|----|-------|---|
| 1  | one   | 1 |
| 2  | two   | 2 |
| 3  | three | 3 |

And the **C** database looks like
| id | name  | A |
|----|-------|---|
| 1  | oneC   | 1 |
| 2  | twoC   | 1 |
| 3  | threeC | 1 |
| 4  | fourC  | 2 |
| 5  | fiveC  | 2 |
| 6  | sixC   | 2 |
| 7  | sevenC | 3 |
| 8  | eightC | 3 |
| 9  | nineC  | 3 |

What I want returned is an object somehow representing the following
| B.name | C.name |
|--------|-------|
|  one   | oneC  |
|  one   | twoC  |
|  one   | threeC|
|  ...   | etc.. |

Comment: Use a OneToOneField in `B`, follow it and use the reverse relationship to `C` from there.

Comment: @KlausD. does that get me a combined list of both B and C? Just added an example to my question

Comment: Well, Django's ORM does not return tables. You will get single objects or lists of objects from a relationship.

Comment: Right, but is there a way to get a list of objects representing that combined list? If not, what impact will changing the ForeignKey to a OneToOneField have, because adding a new OneToOneField would be redundant, wouldn't it? @KlausD.